# How to export ERD diagram to image in oracle data modeler/sql developer

Tags: entity, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-modeling, entity-relationship

I'm on oracle sql developer 4.0.2.15. I used data modeller to generate Entity Relationship Diagram, how to save it as image? I need it to create documentation for my project.

Comment: In my opinion, this question does not show any research effort

Answer (score 25):

File > Data Modeler > Print Diagram > To Image

[image]

Here's the Image File

[image]

And now available in newer versions, 17.x, the HTML/SVG

[image]

You can also generate HTML for your model's data dictionary AND include the diagrams as well. I talk more about that, [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/05/generating-a-data-dictionary-report-and-diagram-for-a-subview/).

Comment: It didn't work for me... It's Output Nothing, my oracle data modeler version 4.0.3.853

Comment: how big is your diagram, number of objects? anything in the log panel? you can also try version 4.1.2

Comment: 845 object also there's nothing in log panel, I just want to take 3 object in relation and it fails. Something wrong with my oracle data modeler ?

Comment: probably running out of memory, that would be a REALLY big diagram. so add 2 or 3 GB of memory to the JVM or create a subview of just those 3 objects and relations, and print that instead

Comment: Alright, I'll try it first. And come back to you... :D

Comment: In version 4.2 which is in Beta right now, you can now also publish your models to HTML and the diagrams are embedded/included.